# Dynamic buttons added to the page, don't know how to find the element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have a complected structure of the page and I have no idea how to find the element...

The page contains folders that are created by a user, I need to create a folder and then to click on it, but I have no idea how to find the element that I've created. The structure look like this:

```
<div class="row-text" style="width: calc(100% - 84px);">
   <span class="row-item-name">
    <span class="row-item-link">
      <a class="grid-row-element-name">Eclipse111</a>
    </span>
   <span class="row-item-actions hover-child">
      <a>Share</a><span> | </span><a watchdox-rename="name" watchdox-save-func="rename(element, name)" class="rename-link"><span translate="">Rename</span></a>
   </span>
   </span>
   <br>
   <span class="row-meta-data">
    <span class="creation-date-formatted">Today at  10:30 | </span>
   <span class="row-email">orgadmin@mailinator.com</span>
   </span>
</div>
<div class="grid-row-buttons">
   <div class="row-tools">
      <div class="btn-group dropdown" uib-dropdown="">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default uib-dropdown-toggle clear-button dropdown-toggle" uib-dropdown-toggle="" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="icon-wd-material-menu"></span>
         </button>
         <ul uib-dropdown-menu="" class="dropdown-menu-highZ contextual-menu dropdown-menu" role="menu">
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The class="grid-row-element-name" contains the name of the folder  that was created (each folder has its own )....

I have no idea how to continue with the testing cause I am not able to click on the folder....

Thank you.

Comment: Am I correct that you don't know how to construct a locator for the folder?  What are you actually trying to find here?  It would help to see the div (?) that wraps all of the code you are showing here.  My guess is that there's another layer of wrapping that wraps up the "folder" with the associated buttons.  It would help to see that layer.

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on how to ask a good question. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried reduced to a [mcve], and what the result was... any error messages, etc. It's also very important to include any relevant HTML and properly format the HTML and code.

Comment: selva helped me.
Thank you for your interest to help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following, since you said "grid-row-element-name" has the folder name then trying using that class name in cssSelector.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a.grid-row-element-name"));
        String folderName = null; //name of the folder which you want to click.

        for (WebElement ele : elements) { //Iterate over the loop 
            if (ele.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(folderName)) {
                ele.click();//once the folder you want is found go for the click.
            }
        }
        //OR
        //To click on the last element try this
        elements.get(elements.size()-1).click();
```

Comment: This is a great progress! I do find the elements now, however the text is not found...

Comment: are you getting any error? can you past the full error log here

Comment: Clicked on Enter by mistake :-)


This is a great progress! I do find the elements now, however the text is not found...
When I am debuging, i see that the amount of the folder is the correct amount, but when looking at the elements, I am getting "RemoteWebElement" with the following properties:
foundBy = [FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (6095e0ff-665b-479c-b934-cbf75b5d9603)] -> css selector: a.grid-row-element-name
id = xxxx
mouse = RemoteMouse
parent = FirefoxDrive

I can't see the text....

Comment: No, no errors, just it doesn't find the text for some reason

Comment: ok have you tried the click  elements.get(elements.size()-1).click();

Comment: Yeap, It works however I am not able to access the correct folder...

Thanks again for your help

Comment: (ele.getAttribute("innerHTML") worked!!!!

if (ele.getAttribute("innerHTML").equalsIgnoreCase(workspaceName)) {
    ele.click();// once the folder you want is found go for the
       // click.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for an element with specific text that you have created (the folder name), I would approach this by looking for an `A` tag that contains the folder name.

BTW, you didn't tag your question with a language so the below is Java. You should be able to convert it easily to another language by just reusing the XPath, if needed.

```
String folderName = "Eclipse111";
// create folder
WebElement folder = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='" + folderName + "']"));
```

Comment: Thank you for trying selva helped me!